# how to disabled selection changed in the details of the dataGrid? (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a dataGrid that use Tareas as items source. This object has a property ICollection as items source of the details.

Also I have a command in my view model that has the code to execute when I select a row in my main data grid. However, when I select a row in the data grid of the details I get an error because is not possible to convert TareasHistorico to Tareas. I nthe code of the method I have a cast.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the execution of the selection changed in the data grid of the details.

I could use an if in my view model to check if the type that I try to cast is the expected type, but I think that this is not a good way to solve the problem, because I guess that this problem is not really a problem of the view model but it is of the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below  whichever u are able to get

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

or

```
e.Handled = true;
```

as First line of Code in DataGrid Selection Changed event.

Comment: But in this way I can't execute the code when I select a row in the main dataGrid. I need another option. But thanks anyway.

Comment: if u want to execute any code in selection changed event and dont want to handle only selection change then u can write that code before writing above line and after that you can do e.cancel or e.Handled true after this and please mark it as answer if it really helps you